How to fix "this item isn't available" for a google play store app?
I have published one Android app in Google Play Store for many years.
Recently, I am getting complains from new users that they cannot download the app from the official store.
I do not know why they see the message "this item isn't available"!
There is no explanation why.
The app is build with
targetSdkVersion 34 is in gradle
minSdkVersion 21
Question:
How can I troubleshoot this further to identify the root cause and fix it?

Hi, the min and target sdk are listed in my question. I updated my app last week

The screenshot shows the PEGI 18 logo I assume that is for your app. Have you chosen to make your app only available for adults or is this the result of missing age classification? This may have an impact on the availability of your app on certain accounts that are not age verified.
